# Why do i have a segmentation fault (core dump) with big multidimensional array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have this simple program which has to receive in input a `matrix[d][d]` with every element separated by a `,` whenever is given the input `AddM`, then it is supposed to print the matrix.

It works well when the `d` is small, let's say around `20`, but if I enter a larger `d` then it gives me a segmentation fault (core dump) error.

Can somebody explain why it has this behaviour?
Thank you for your time and sorry if my question is stupid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGHT 5

int menu(char c[]);
int **buildAdjMat(int **m);

int d;

int main() {
    char *command;
    int m_result = 1;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int **m;

    if (scanf("%d", &d) == 0)
        return 0;
    printf("d: %d\n", d);

    m = (int **)malloc(d * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        m[i] = (int *)malloc(d * sizeof(int));
    }

    do {
        command = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGHT);

        if (scanf("%s", command) == 0)
            return 0;

        m_result = menu(command);
        if (m_result == 1) {
            m = buildAdjMat(m);

            for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                    printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            free(command);
        } else {
            printf("End! with value %d", m_result);
            free(command);
        }
    } while(m_result == 1);

    free(m);

    return 0;
}

int menu(char c[]) {

    if (strcmp(c, "AddM") == 0) {
        printf("AddM!\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int **buildAdjMat(int **m) {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char c = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &m[i][j]) == 0)
                return NULL;
            if (scanf("%c", &c) == 0)
                return NULL;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that strings in C are ***null-terminated** arrays* of characters? A string of four characters (like `"AddM"`) need space for five characters to include the terminator.

Comment: Also why do the dynamic allocation of `command`? Why not declare it as an actual array?

Comment: After `m=buildAdjMat(m);` you don't check for `NULL` returned before dereferencing. If the `scanf` fails `NULL` is explicitly returned.

Comment: Editing the code from `#define MAX_LENGHT 4` to `5` now throws doubt as to what your true code is. Just present the *actual code* please and don't make the question like shifting sand.

Comment: By the way, in the `buildAdjMat` function, what happens if the input ends *without* a comma? For example for a 2x2 matrix, if the input is e.g. `1,2,3,4` then your code would return a `NULL` for what is otherwise valid input. Your code uses the comma not only as separator but also as a terminator.

Comment: Some programmer dude, sorry, but it wasn't the problem. I left 4 in the define just because i switched the language of the input AddM! it was "AggiungiGrafo" with max_lenght 14 before. When i changed i didnt pay attention.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to learn how to use a debugger. Then you can run your program in it and catch the crash as and when it happens, and be able to locate exactly where in your code it happens, and also examine the values of all involved variables to make sure they seem okay.

Comment: Instead of `scanf("%s", command)` do `scanf("%4s", command)`, to avoid buffer overflows (with your new buffer size of `5`).

Comment: There are memory leaks and some other questionable code, as pointed out by others, but I cannot seem to reproduce the segfault. What do you consider a "bigger d"?

Comment: It does not work with d=400. Also i have to use -DEVAL -std=gnu11 -O2 -pipe -static parameters to compile

Comment: I've done all of the fixes you suggested and now it works! Thank you so much

Comment: With that many allocations you might run into fragmentation issues. Perhaps allocate as a single large chunk of memory (`d * d * sizeof(int)`) and use index-calculations to reach each element in the matrix?

Comment: Furthermore, ***always*** check if `malloc` succeeds or fails.

Comment: `scanf("%s", command)` womp womp

Comment: If if you have a core dump, the first step is to examine it.  It provides a great deal of useful diagnostic information and learning to use it is well worth the time.

Comment: Is this C, or C++?  It looks mostly like C, but `int main()` and casting malloc are more commonly found in C++.  (Why anyone uses `malloc` in C++ at all is a different question.)

Comment: @M.M - _womp womp_ cute, but not easily translatable.

Comment: FWIW - I have run your code as is with one change:  Added `srand(clock())` to top of `buildAdjMat()` function, then replaced the 4 lines under the `for()` statement with `m[i][j] = rand();
            c = rand()%255;`.  And I have tried `d==50` and `d==100` and `d==1000`.  None of them caused a `seg-fault`.  Although `d==1000` was painfully long.  The only potential problem is if you write more than `4` characters into `scanf("%s", command)`.  That will cause undefined behavior, and often a `seg-fault`.  Voting to close as your stated problem is not reproducible.